# jQuery - Change an iframe width of a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am facing a problem that I need to change the width of an iframe in a child node.

For example:

```
<div id="pNode">
  <div>
      <iframe>...</iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are no IDs for childnode and iframe. How can I change the width?

Answer (score 0):

Simply  select the iframe, assuming the structure in your question:

```
$('#pNode div iframe').attr('width',/* Your width */)
```